# rails authlogic can't find current_user (nil) after using http basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authlogic

I am using

rails => 3.0.20

authlogic => 3.0.3

before using http basic authentication it is all okay.
But after using it, after login successfully with 'http basic user name and pass'
I have to log in with application user name and password which is retrived from database. It is also sucessfully done. Then it is redirected to a default method  which requires current user. But `current user` returns `nil`.  `UserSession.find` also returns `nil`

any idea about why session objects return nil ?

Comment: can you show us your controller code?

Comment: You can also try adding `allow_http_basic_auth false` in your `UserSession` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `authlogic` and `rails 3`, I believe it could be work if you add below code in `user_session.rb` model:

```
 class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
    allow_http_basic_auth false
 end
```

> Not sure why this is a problem with this Rails/Authlogic/HTTP
>   combination, but anyways, the fix was to add this one-liner to your
>   UserSession model

Thumbs up to `Chris Irish` [here](http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/08/12/rails-3-authlogic-sessions-not-persisting-in-production/comment-page-1) I found this in his blog.